Expo Android app crashing right after launch, iOS working, new NativeEventEmitter() was called
I build app using Expo and discovered that the Android version of my app is crashing right after launch (iOS version is working). I reproduced this by launching "npx expo start --no-dev --minify" but in normal dev mode app is working.
Console is silent, only warning which I see in Expo Go is "new NativeEventEmitter() was called..." but I can't read it all, it's cut in half and it's not possible to open this warning and see details.
I updated dependencies (below) and tried debug with Sentry but it seems that bug occurs before App.tsx is launched because I didn't log anything.
Can you help me what is going on and why Expo isn't logging any errors?
My dependencies:
{
"name": "mobile",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
"@types/react": "~18.2.79",
"axios": "^1.7.2",
"d3": "^7.9.0",
"expo": "~51.0.8",
"expo-auth-session": "~5.5.2",
"expo-image-manipulator": "~12.0.5",
"expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5",
"expo-linking": "^6.3.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"expo-updates": "~0.25.14",
"expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
"lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.2",
"react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
"react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.12",
"typescript": "~5.3.3",
"expo-image": "~1.12.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.24.6"
},
"private": true
}

Environment:
expo-env-info 1.2.0 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
Binaries:
Node: 20.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm: 10.1.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
npmPackages:
expo: ~51.0.8 => 51.0.8
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.74.1 => 0.74.1
react-native-web: ~0.19.12 => 0.19.12
Expo Workflow: managed

Expo Doctor Diagnostics:
✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check native tooling versions
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check for issues with metro config
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Didn't find any issues with the project!
